# How to access a specific field of a document in firebase firestore using flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to access specific fields in firestore documents using document ID. Is there a way to access the filed by entering document ID instead of this way? => NetworkImage(snapshot.data!.docs[3]['image1']),

I need to put the string value of the document ID to docs, which is more readable

Here is my code:

```
StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
            stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                .collection('destinations').snapshots(),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                return const Center(
                  child: Text(
                    'Loading...',
                    style: TextStyle(
                        fontFamily: 'Bangers',
                        fontSize: 16,
                        color: Colors.teal),
                  ),
                );
              }
              if (snapshot.hasError) {
                return const Text('Something went wrong.');
              }
              final data = snapshot.requireData;
              return ListView(
                padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                children: [
                  Container(
                    height: 400,
                    width: double.infinity,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.teal,
                      image: DecorationImage(
                          image: NetworkImage(snapshot.data!.docs[3]['image1']),
                          fit: BoxFit.cover),
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                        bottomRight: Radius.circular(50),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                 .
                 .
                 .
                 .
                 .
                 .
                 .
```

Comment: Hi, Can you please explain a bit more about the problem that you are facing with the current code?

Comment: I want to access the firestore document by using its unique ID just like this => NetworkImage(snapshot.data!.docs[DOCUMENT-1]['image1']. But I can only parse an int value to docs.

Comment: I don't think it is possible with doc id as .docs returns an array , and you will have to use a index value to retrieve a single document or iterate over it.